# Difference between allure generate report and allure serve

Tags: java, testng, allure

I'm wondering what the difference is between allure report commands 'generate' and 'serve'.

When I enter 'allure --help' in my terminal then I see default explanation that doesn't help a lot.

```
  generate      Generate the report
  Usage: generate [options] The directories with allure results

  serve      Serve the report
  Usage: serve [options] The directories with allure results
```

Could anyone explain when should I use 'generate' or 'serve' to get a report?

I use Selenium + TestNg + Allure2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allure generate, just generate allure-report directory, with all test results resources. Allure serve start a web server, with results, dashboards, etc. Allure serve depends on allure report directory. So, if you need to open web server with test results, you need to execute allure generate before allure serve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).